# JavaScript not running with when other libraries are also included

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote the following javascript code

```
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>

<script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>

<script src="js/freelancer.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>
</head>

<body> 
<div id="accordion" style="width:50%"></div>
<script>
var html = '';
var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ..';
for(var i=0 ; i<6 ; i++) {
  html += '<h3>Section ' + i + '</h3>' + '<div><p>' + text + '</p></div>';
}
document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML = html;

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

it works well when i run it alone, but when i include it in bootstrap, it doesn't work.
I think the problem is with the libraries i add, but i am not sure.
here is the libraries:

```
<link href="css/form_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/freelancer.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>
<script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
<script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>
<script src="js/freelancer.js"></script>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you are including a lot of libraries, you will certainly need to give us a line number and/or error you are getting.

Comment: Looks to me as if you're importing 3 different copies of jQuery.

Comment: Why are you including multiple versions of jQuery and Bootstrap?

Comment: Look in the browser's error console. What errors do you see there? Then look in the console's network tab. Are all scripts loaded correctly?

Comment: There is no errors in the console.

Comment: I removed this one: 
    `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`
But nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the HTML code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>
</head>

<body> 
<div id="accordion" style="width:50%"></div>
<script>
var html = '';
var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ..';
for(var i=0 ; i<6 ; i++) {
  html += '<h3>Section ' + i + '</h3>' + '<div><p>' + text + '</p></div>';
}
document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML = html;

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would recommend using cdn

Comment: my guess is `<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` is breaking it

Comment: Alway put "Jquery Library" at the top